# How to call and run a Python file inside another from a variable

Tags: python

I am using Python version : 2.6.6. I have a Python code test2.py inside directory : /home/admin.

And i am trying to run the file from inside : /home/admin/Practice/test.py.

My test.py code contains :

```
import os
filedir = os.path.realpath(__file__)
scriptdir = os.path.dirname(filedir)
print (filedir)
print (scriptdir)
newfile = scriptdir + "/../" + "test2.py"
new_module = __import__(newfile)
exec("python new_module 100 10"
```

Now i know this is probably not the right way to run a Python script from another. But when i run this i get :

```
[admin@centos1 Practice]$ python test.py
/home/admin/Practice/test.py
/home/admin/Practice
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    new_module = __import__(newfile)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

We have to run the Python script : /home/admin/test2.py which is inside the variable : newfile inside test.py.

Can someone please guide me as to how this should be done?

Thanks for the learning.

Comment: did you tried with the following line:
newfile = scriptdir + "/../" + "test2"

Comment: `execfile` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommends to use `execfile`. In fact you just needs to learn how imports works in Python, you are learning Python right ?

You have several ways to handle this.

The easiest way is to package everything in a single module, saying `mytest`.

1. Create a directory named `mytest`
2. Create a file `mytest/__init__.py` ([Why __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for))
3. Copy your files: `mytest/test.py`, `mytest/test2.py` (you should change names too, but that is not the point here.)
4. In your file `mytest/test.py` just do `import test2` and all code in `test2` will be executed.

A better way is to encapsulate code in `test2.py` within function like:

```
def foo():
    # your code here
```

So in `test.py` you can do:

```
import test2
test2.foo()
```

---

So assuming that your code in `test2.py` is:

```
print "Hello world!"
```

My proposal will result by something like:

file `mytests/__init__.py` empty.

file `mytest/test.py`:

```
import test2
test2.my_function_name()
```

file `mytest/test2.py`:

```
def my_function_name():
    print "Hello world!"
```

And you can run it with: `python mytest/test.py`

A last thing, you should rename the file `test.py` by `__main__.py` if you use it as command-line entry point ([More about __main__](https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/ed19c5d9ba9bb50391a2)).

Answer (score 0):

You can run the contents of another Python file using the built-in function [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile). That is `execfile(filename)` executes the statements in the file which is pointed to by `filename` in the current scope.